# Unable to move the OBJPROP_TEXT with the OBJ_HLINE in MQL4

Tags: mql4

I have a function in MQL4 to create a horizontal line and I am adding in a Text to the line. However, I want this to be moved to the right side of the chart.

[image: chart]

I have tried setting up the anchor and alignment but none of these work as the text is being formed with the HLINE Object not seperatly.

```
//Create a horizontal line on a chart
void drawDashedHorizontalLine(string id, double price, color clr, bool displayLineName=false) {
   ENUM_LINE_STYLE style         = STYLE_DASHDOT;
   
   ObjectCreate(0, id, OBJ_HLINE, 0, 0, price);
   ObjectMove(0, id, 0, 0, price);
   ObjectSetInteger(0, id, OBJPROP_STYLE, style); // Line style
   ObjectSetInteger(0, id, OBJPROP_COLOR, clr); // Line color
   if (displayLineName) { 
      ObjectSetString(0, id, OBJPROP_TEXT, id);
   }
}
```

Any help would be much appriciated

Cheers